# Remember Page Session

Tags: php, mysqli

So I'm looking for the best advice on how to tackle a problem. I wanted to allow my members to be able to stayed logged in on devices when they checked "Keep me logged in". But after researching I found out that cookies would do it, but it's not secure.

So my second idea was instead just remember the page they were on and go back to it after logging back in. Simple enough. More secure(theoretically).

But the only way I can think of is by making a table in the database that records the current page the member goes to, and updates it each time the go to a new one.

Is this the best way to approach the solution, or are there any better ways? I'm open to all suggestions, and could not find any solutions elsewhere in the forums. (I'm using PHP and MYSQLi)

Comment: do you want your members to get to the last page they visited each time they are logging in? is that correct?

Comment: Regardless of what you do, you can never promise complete security. The very premise of always logged in, is insecure. But I don't think that's what you're after. I'm leaning towards you actually wanting to retrieve the page they were on, during the previous visit?

Comment: @Fadey, yes, essentially. I'm just trying to find the best way to do it because if I have a thousand users getting there last page updated every time they go to a new page, that'll be a lot of processing on the server.

Comment: @LokiSinclair, you are spot on, sir/madam. I want security over ease.

Comment: @logicK if you want to save their last page for each future login you'll have to save that into the DB. It doesnt mean you can't design it smart enough to be efficient and low coasting performance wise. If you only save their last visited page, it's secure enough.

Comment: Yeah all the research I've done is suggesting the same thing. I had an idea of using a cookie to save the last page, and then just running a line of code that says something like if the session is set, go to the last page that computer was on? Think that might be do-able?

Comment: "getting there last page updated every time they go to a new page, that'll be a lot of processing on the server"  Hardly. This will be a trivial task and for most modern websites would be inconsequential compared to everything else being done.

Comment: @PatrickQ, hmm, well I was mainly worried about it on a large scale. But if you think it won't be an issue, I'll take your word for it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is to use a combination of cookies and session to do this. Or even secure cookies. Check out this link.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_cookie

Comment: This is what I've been looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

try to use one of the function in this guide.
[DOM Storage Guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage)

i never tested it but i what think you need is the localstorage.

or this [Using IndexedDB](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API/Using_IndexedDB)

Comment: thanks, I'll give this a look and see if I can find something helpful. :)